# Как обойти проблему дубликата ключа и на чем основано?

Tags: sql, mysql

[image: лучший сайт в мире]
 открыть картинку в новой вкладке=3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну может стоит убрать уникальность поля!?

Ошибка же явно пишется, про дублирование ключа!

Comment: это моя первая бд
как я мог узнать про УНИКАЛЬНОСТЬ
если забыл что её оставил
что тут намекает на уникальность. чтобы и я мог понять.
спасибо